# dlib image conversion to opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, dlib

I just tested the http://dlib.net/face_landmark_detection_ex.cpp.html example.

The Question is now: Is there a proper way to covert the image type of tile_images(face_chips) to a Mat object?

Thanks in advance
Alex

Comment: Solved the issue
For people with the same problem:
You have to make a copy of the output of tile_images and pass it to dlib::toMat.

Answer (score 2):

You should call [dlib::toMat](http://dlib.net/imaging.html#toMat) to do this.

Comment: already tried this but giving me an
invalid initialization of non-const reference of type error.
Maybe i have to make a copy of the output of tile_images adn give it to dlib::toMat?